# Saving XML in UTF-8 with MSXML

Tags: xml, localization, vbscript, utf-8, msxml

I'm trying to load a simple Xml file (encoded in UTF-8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test/>
```

And save it with MSXML in vbscript:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

xmlDoc.Load("C:\test.xml")

xmlDoc.Save "C:\test.xml"
```

The problem is, MSXML saves file in ANSI instead of UTF-8 (despite the original file being encoded in UTF-8).

The [MSDN docs for MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769(VS.85).aspx) says that save() will write the file in whatever encoding the XML is defined in:

> Character encoding is based on the encoding attribute in the XML declaration, such as . When no encoding attribute is specified, the default setting is UTF-8.

But this is clearly not working at least on my machine.

How can MSXML save in UTF-8?

Comment: I don't see the behavior you're reporting.  When I run that code, it saves the XML document in UTF-8.  I get a UTF-8 declaration, and the actual strings are in UTF-8.

Comment: Yeh, it could very well only be my machine (Win2k3) and my colleague's (Win2k8 64bit) that's having this problem. It will be nice if someone can say definitively why the behavior differs amongst machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any non-ANSI text in your XML file, so it will be identical whether UTF-8 or ASCII encoded.  In my tests, after adding non-ASCII text to test.xml, MSXML always saves in UTF-8 encoding and also writes the BOM if there was one to begin with.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: And so I guess there's no way MSXML can save in UTF-8 if there's no unicode bytes in the file?

Comment: By definition, there is no difference between an ASCII and UTF-8 file if it contains only ASCII characters (except for the BOM if included)...

Answer (score 4):

You use two other classes in MSXML to write out XML properly encoded to an output stream.

Here is my helper method that writes to a generic IStream:

```
class procedure TXMLHelper.WriteDocumentToStream(const Document60: IXMLDOMDocument2; const stream: IStream; Encoding: string = 'UTF-8');
var
    writer: IMXWriter;
    reader: IVBSAXXMLReader;
begin
{
    From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275883
    INFO: XML Encoding and DOM Interface Methods

    MSXML has native support for the following encodings:
        UTF-8
        UTF-16
        UCS-2
        UCS-4
        ISO-10646-UCS-2
        UNICODE-1-1-UTF-8
        UNICODE-2-0-UTF-16
        UNICODE-2-0-UTF-8

    It also recognizes (internally using the WideCharToMultibyte API function for mappings) the following encodings:
        US-ASCII
        ISO-8859-1
        ISO-8859-2
        ISO-8859-3
        ISO-8859-4
        ISO-8859-5
        ISO-8859-6
        ISO-8859-7
        ISO-8859-8
        ISO-8859-9
        WINDOWS-1250
        WINDOWS-1251
        WINDOWS-1252
        WINDOWS-1253
        WINDOWS-1254
        WINDOWS-1255
        WINDOWS-1256
        WINDOWS-1257
        WINDOWS-1258
}

    if Document60 = nil then
        raise Exception.Create('TXMLHelper.WriteDocument: Document60 cannot be nil');
    if stream = nil then
        raise Exception.Create('TXMLHelper.WriteDocument: stream cannot be nil');

    // Set properties on the XML writer - including BOM, XML declaration and encoding
    writer := CoMXXMLWriter60.Create;
    writer.byteOrderMark := True; //Determines whether to write the Byte Order Mark (BOM). The byteOrderMark property has no effect for BSTR or DOM output. (Default True)
    writer.omitXMLDeclaration := False; //Forces the IMXWriter to skip the XML declaration. Useful for creating document fragments. (Default False)
    writer.encoding := Encoding; //Sets and gets encoding for the output. (Default "UTF-16")
    writer.indent := True; //Sets whether to indent output. (Default False)
    writer.standalone := True;

    // Set the XML writer to the SAX content handler.
    reader := CoSAXXMLReader60.Create;
    reader.contentHandler := writer as IVBSAXContentHandler;
    reader.dtdHandler := writer as IVBSAXDTDHandler;
    reader.errorHandler := writer as IVBSAXErrorHandler;
    reader.putProperty('http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler', writer);
    reader.putProperty('http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler', writer);


    writer.output := stream; //The resulting document will be written into the provided IStream

    // Now pass the DOM through the SAX handler, and it will call the writer
    reader.parse(Document60);

    writer.flush;
end;
```

In order to save to a file i call the **Stream** version with a **FileStream**:

```
class procedure TXMLHelper.WriteDocumentToFile(const Document60: IXMLDOMDocument2; const filename: string; Encoding: string='UTF-8');
var
    fs: TFileStream;
begin
    fs := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
        TXMLHelper.WriteDocumentToStream(Document60, fs, Encoding);
    finally
        fs.Free;
    end;
end;
```

You can convert the functions to whatever language you like. These are Delphi.

Comment: I am going to make use of James Bond hobby and try to resurrect this thread. In C++ type library I have the following definition of putProperty method:
`HRESULT ISAXXMLReader::putProperty ( unsigned short * pwchName, const _variant_t & varValue )`
 this requires unsigned short pointer as a parameter. By any chance you know whether there are any enums or #defines for supported properties or how could I specify `lexical-handler` and `declaration-handler` properties?

Comment: @wenaxus I don't even know what `lexical-handler` or `declaration-handler` are! :)  You should probably ask that as a full new question.

Comment: Fair enough, I just saw you were using them in your answer: ` reader.putProperty('http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler', writer);` and thought I give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform `load` msxml does not copy *encoding* from the processing instruction into the created document. So it doesn't contain any encoding and seems like msxml chooses something which it likes. In my environment it's UTF-16 which I don't prefer.

The solution is to provide processing instructions and specify encoding there. If you know that the document has no processing instructions, the code is trivial:

```
Set pi = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", _
         "version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1250""")
If xmlDoc.childNodes.Length > 0 Then
  Call xmlDoc.insertBefore(pi, xmlDoc.childNodes.Item(0))
End If
```

If it's possible, that the document contained other processing instruction, it must be removed first (so the code below must come before the code above). I don't know how to use `selectNode` to do it, so I just iterated all root nodes:

```
For ich=xmlDoc.childNodes.Length-1 to 0 step -1
  Set ch = xmlDoc.childNodes.Item(ich)
  If ch.NodeTypeString = "processinginstruction" and ch.NodeName = "xml" Then
    xmlDoc.removeChild(ch)
  End If
Next ich
```

*Sorry if the code doesn't execute directly, because I modified working version, that was written in something custom, not vbscript.*

Comment: I searched all over the place to find a way to remove a processing instruction from an xml file using vbScript; this was the only example of a way to do it that I saw (Once I did I felt dumb of course). Select node or nodes does not seem to work because a processing instruction is not in the document element which is where select node and Xpath starts searching from.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround seems to work: passing the xml string to ADODB.Stream to save the file.

Update: the processing instruction get lost according to this:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms755989(v=vs.85)
> The xml property always returns a Unicode string. That is, the xml property for DOMDocument converts the document from its original encoding to Unicode. As a result, the original encoding attribute is removed.

```
Sub Facturae()
On Error GoTo ExceptionHandling

Dim i As Integer

'Declare document objects
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xRoot As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

'Create new DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument60

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms755989(v=vs.85
'Add the XML declaration as a processing instruction:
'Dim xmlDecl As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
'Set xmlDecl = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'")
'xDoc.appendChild xmlDecl

'Create the root element
Set xRoot = xDoc.createElement("fe:Facturae")
xDoc.appendChild xRoot

'The namespace declarations are attributes on the root element, so you can add them using:
xRoot.setAttribute "xmlns:ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
xRoot.setAttribute "xmlns:fe", "http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2009/v3.2/Facturae"
'xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
'xDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:fe", "http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2009/v3.2/Facturae"

'Add child to root
'Create security element
Dim objSecElem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Set objSecElem = xDoc.createElement("Security")
xRoot.appendChild objSecElem

Dim str(1 To 3) As String
str(1) = "A"
str(2) = "B"
str(3) = "C"

Dim objProp As IXMLDOMElement
For i = 1 To UBound(str)
    Set objProp = xDoc.createElement(str(i))
    objSecElem.appendChild objProp
    objProp.Text = i
Next i

Dim objStream As Stream, strData As String, sFilePath As String
'Debug.Print xDoc.XML
strData = xDoc.XML
sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\my_file.xml"

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeText
objStream.charset = "utf-8"
objStream.LineSeparator = adCRLF
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>", adWriteLine
objStream.WriteText strData, adWriteChar
objStream.SaveToFile sFilePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite

'Save the XML file
'xDoc.Save sFilePath

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    objStream.Close
    Exit Sub
ExceptionHandling:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanUp
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205786/excel-vba-global-variables-are-assigned-when-workbook-is-opened-get-erased-if?rq=1
    'error handler
    'Note the unreachable Resume at the end of the error handler. It's unreachable because Resume ExitProcedure will always execute first.
    'So when you get the messagebox, you can use ctrl+break to break into code, which will then take you to the Resume ExitProcedure.
    'You can then drag the yellow arrow over to the unreachable Resume, press F8 to step once which will then take you back to the line that caused the error.
    Resume 'for debugging
End Sub
```