# Excel vba: global variables are assigned when workbook is opened; get erased if an error occurs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has global variables declared:

```
Public var1 As Long
Public var2 As Long
Public var3 As Long
...
Public varN As Long
```

I also have a workbook open sub that assigns values to global variables when a workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Call calculateRows
    Call assignVariables


    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filling").Protect "somepass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    MsgBox ("DONE Workbook_open")
End Sub
```

It works fine. However, I also have a worksheet selection change sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub
```

and worksheet change sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub
```

which both contain code that can end up with an error. Whatever error occurs, it always erases the value of my global variables, which only leads to further errors and basically a complete shutdown of the workbook since all the worksheet selection/change subs heavily use those global variables.

What I should do to ensure it wouldn't happen? Would using an 'On Error GoTo' operation be sufficient? Why would global variables get erased anyway?

Comment: Why are you allowing the possibility of errors in your code?  That should be the main concern here.  There's not enough information to really help you.

Comment: @tigeravatar What information do you find lacking? My post isn't about how to avoid the errors; it's about how to avoid getting the globals erased.

Comment: Proper error trapping should prevent your VBA project from resetting. You could also declare a new global Boolean variable called `Initialized`, modify `assignVariables` so that this variable is set to `True` and throw in the line `If Not Initialized Then assignVariables` at the top of your other event handlers. That won't fix the core problem but might provide a bit of a safety net.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, your code should be robust enough to avoid errors, or trap them so that the code exits gracefully.  This means your main problem is that your code produces unhandled errors.  Fixing that will fix your global variable problem.  You haven't provided the contents of your code so there's nothing for us to analyze to try to help.  You're also conflating the issue by trying to get a workaround instead of address the main problem. That's called [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Unhandled errors lead to state loss, which is when your globals get reset. If you can't avoid using globals, or avoid the errors, you need to use error handling.

Comment: State is lost when you click the "End" button, just as it would be if you clicked the "Stop" button in the IDE/debugger, executed an `End` instruction, or ran an `End` statement in the *immediate pane*. If your program wasn't hosted in Excel, allowing an error/exception to bubble up and out of the entry point means your program crashes and burns, its process is terminated, and all state is lost. Don't let run-time errors bubble up beyond your entry point; worksheet event handlers **must** catch all errors. Also, using globals might not be the best design.

Comment: @tigeravatar I don't argue with that unhandled errors is a bad thing, but everyone's situation is different. I might be working with a big legacy code that I can not go through and redo quickly; but I can do a quick fix to prevent serious problems. If you think you have nothing to analyze to help, you don't have to. Other people seem to be commenting even with the limited information I've provided.

Comment: @Ans this isn't something people have an *opinion* on. Letting errors bubble up beyond the entry point kills your app, period, flat fact. Don't do this.

Comment: @John Coleman That's an interesting solution, thank you. Where should I put the check on the `If Not Initialized`? Into `On Error` block?

Comment: @Ans To make that clear: *What I should do to ensure it wouldn't happen?* - Catch the errors. Nothing else helps. *Would using an 'On Error GoTo' operation be sufficient?* - In some general sense, yes. We don't have enough information to tell exactly. *Why would global variables get erased anyway?* - As Mathieu Guindon already mentioned: Any unhandled error will cause state loss. No way around that. (Well, except maybe storing the state at certain points in the workbook and then restoring it. It's quite the hassle.)

Comment: @Ans Put it as the first line in the sub. It shouldn't be used as a replacement for Error handling. Note that it wouldn't help if the global variables need to be modified by some of the procedures -- but if they are read-only variables which e.g. assign a fixed range to a range variable, then this is a way to guarantee that none of the event handlers will run without the variables being properly assigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, clicking `End` to halt the execution will always reset the global state. Heck, there need not be an error; clicking the Stop button will have the same effect.

You should have error handling at least within the entry procedures (e.g. your worksheet event handlers are good candidates since they are the entry point where Excel can interact with your VBA code).

If you want to be able to find the offending error even with a error handler, this pattern can help:

```
Public Sub Example()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Some code that might error

ExitProcedure:
On Error Resume Next
'Clean up
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Oops"
Resume ExitProcedure
Resume 'for debugging

End Sub
```

Note the unreachable `Resume` at the end of the error handler. It's unreachable because `Resume ExitProcedure` will always execute first. So when you get the messagebox, you can use `ctrl+break` to break into code, which will then take you to the `Resume ExitProcedure`. You can then drag the yellow arrow over to the unreachable `Resume`, press F8 to step once which will then take you back to the line that caused the error.

Note that it only works for in procedure; if error was bubbled, it will return you to the procedure that was called before the error bubbled but not the line within the procedure.

Or, if you don't like all extra work, you can consider buying an addin such as [vbWatchDog](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp)  which helps significantly with the error handling.

Even so, those do not help with the root problem -- the global state is fragile and can be destroyed... there's the Stop button or even `End` available for you. You want to avoid using global as much as possible and scope them or stuff them in a class instance so that when you repeat a code block, it can rebuild the state within that scope. The less things you have in the global state, the better.

Comment: I really like your last paragraph. +1.

Comment: A little smarter every day... I did not now you could pause execution with `Ctrl+Break` from MsgBoxes. My usual approach was to try and locate the corresponding `MsgBox` statement and put a breakpoint there. So thanks for the shortcut!

Comment: @Inarion you've never made a program that got out of hand and had to be put down?!

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I've lost a couple of hours' work when "just quickly testing" that shiny new `Do ... Loop` construct, where I accidentally omitted any exit condition. (It didn't have `DoEvents` either, so my desperate keystrokes went unheard by Excel...) So, I basically knew about `Ctrl+Break`, but it never occurred to me to apply it to a MsgBox.

Comment: FYI, `Ctrl+Break` is also useful for breaking infinite loops or even just to break into a code block that's taking too long than it should be. (Note that it cannot interrupt the execution of the instruction itself, so if a line that writes to a file takes 10 minutes, it'll take that long before you finally get that dialog from VBE.)