# Creating a SEPA XML file

Tags: xml, vba, dom

I'm trying to create a SEPA XML file in an old Access application.

I found a mistake in the first lines.

```vb
Dim xmlDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlspacename As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xmlVersion As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
Dim xslStylesheet As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
Set xmlDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Set xmlVersion = xmlDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8'")
xmlDom.appendChild xmlVersion

Set xmlspacename = xmlDom.createElement("Document")
xmlDom.appendChild xmlspacename
xmlDom.documentElement.setAttribute "xmlns", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
xmlDom.documentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlDom.documentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

'****RAIZ DEL MENSAJE
'Creando elemento raiz [1..1]_0
Dim xmlrootnode As IXMLDOMElement
Set xmlrootnode = xmlDom.createElement("CstmrCdtTrfInitn")
xmlspacename.appendChild xmlrootnode
'*****CABECERA
' Creando 1_0_cabecera [1..1]_0
Dim cabecera As IXMLDOMElement
Set cabecera = xmlDom.createElement("GrpHdr")
xmlrootnode.appendChild cabecera

MsgBox "Ok"

' Saves XML data to disk.
xmlDom.Save ("c:\temp\andrew.xml")
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">


      <CstmrCdtTrfInitn xmlns="">

            <GrpHdr/>

        </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>

   </Document>
```

This is the resultant xml file. I compared it with some example files the banks have given me, an there is a diference in this tag:

```
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn xmlns="">
```

I need that the attribute special word 'xmlns' disappears from the tag.

Comment: It's the first time I ask a question in STACKOVERFLOW and it seems to me that te question is incmplete. <CstmrCdtTrfInitn xmlns=""> is the tag I obtain and <CstmrCdtTrfInitn> is the tag i would like to obtain

Comment: You can edit your question via the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58142328/edit) to change/add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
Dim xmlDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlspacename As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xmlVersion As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
Dim xslStylesheet As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
Set xmlDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Set xmlVersion = xmlDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8'")
'xmlDom.appendChild xmlVersion

Set xmlspacename = xmlDom.createElement("Document")
xmlDom.appendChild xmlspacename
'xmlDom.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
'xmlDom.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
'xmlDom.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

'****RAIZ DEL MENSAJE
'Creando elemento raiz [1..1]_0
Dim xmlrootnode As IXMLDOMElement
Set xmlrootnode = xmlDom.createElement("CstmrCdtTrfInitn")
xmlspacename.appendChild xmlrootnode
'*****CABECERA
' Creando 1_0_cabecera [1..1]_0
Dim cabecera As IXMLDOMElement
Set cabecera = xmlDom.createElement("GrpHdr")
xmlrootnode.appendChild cabecera

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596085/saving-xml-in-utf-8-with-msxml
Dim objStream As Stream, strData As String, sFilePath As String
'MsgBox (xmlDom.XML)
'Debug.Print xmlDom.XML
strData = Replace(xmlDom.XML, "<Document>", "<Document xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"">")
sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\andrew.xml"

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeText
objStream.charset = "utf-8"
objStream.LineSeparator = adCRLF
'objStream.LineSeparator = adLF
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'>", adWriteLine
objStream.WriteText strData, adWriteChar
objStream.SaveToFile sFilePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
```